# MySQL Group By Pair of integer range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in MySQL. `Id` and `PictureNo`, `Id` is auto, `PictureNo` only `(1,2,3)` in any order.

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/jjaeyx.jpg]

Question is I would like to retrieve by pair of `pictureNo` as below, order of Id doesn't matter, just need to retrieve by pair, should be `1,2,3`.

[http://i40.tinypic.com/jiku54.jpg http://i40.tinypic.com/jiku54.jpg](http://i40.tinypic.com/jiku54.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: What would happen if your PictureNo values were 3,2,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,3,3,3?

Comment: It'll help if you give us more data, and all the constraints. Like, if you mean that the id order doesn't matter, but should they still be in the same close group? In your example, you have id 3,2 and 1 together grouped with the pictureno 1,2,3 ..followed by 6,4 and 5.. But would it be okay if the grouping was like for one group of pictureno 1,2 and 3 you'll have id 6, 2 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from MyTable order by PictureNo + ID , PictureNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID,PictureNo
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY ID
) AS s
ORDER BY s.ID;
```

Hope it helps